# count jTable exact column for every row

Tags: java, jtable

How can I properly count exact column for every row in jTable ?
I tried this :

Method :

```
public double getTotal(DefaultTableModel dtm){
        for (int i = 0; i <= dtm.getRowCount(); i++) {
            total += (double) Double.parseDouble((String) dtm.getValueAt(i, 2));
            i++;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

And filling table like this :

```
try {
            String name = "Total";
            TechnoRepository repo = TechnoRepository.getInstance();
            DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
                name,
                null,
                String.valueOf(repo.getTotal(dtm))
            });
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FillRacunPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

But it's not work properly...
Goal is to count 3rd column for all rows.

Comment: One correction. I want to count all values from all rows of 3rd column

Comment: Please read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach. I'd look at a `TableModelListener` that updates a view of `total`.

Comment: Thank You for answer. Could You give me some simple example how to use TableModelListener ?

Comment: Perhaps you overlooked *Listening for Data Changes*.